# Android Room - Getting all base children of parent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Right now, my relation hierarchy is `A -> (A -> ... -> A) -> B` where there are some amount (could also be 0) of  `A` in the middle and each arrow is a one-to-many relationship.

- Each `A` "tree" will end in a `B`.
- Each `A` has either `A` or `B` as a child (but not both)

My entities are:

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_A")
data class A(
    id,        // ID of the A
    parentAid  // ID of the parent A (nullable)
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_B")
data class B(
    id,        // ID of this B
    parentAid  // ID of the parent A (non-nullable)
)
```

Currently, my method is to query `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_A WHERE parentAid = :id"` to get the amount of `A` a parent has. If this number is bigger than 0, repeat with each of the child `A`. Else, `SELECT * FROM table_B WHERE parentAid = :id` is run to get the list of `B` which is added to a list.

Is this an effective way of doing things? Is there a query in Room that can easily do this?

Comment: I am facing the exact problem.... have you found any clue?

Comment: https://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html
Have a look at this link, it gives you away to extract all base children of a row in sql then you can make room database relation to the table B

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved as below: (Am using Kotlin syntax, so please relate to convert the solution to Java)

Create  another data class like below:

```
data class TableAWithTableB(
  @Embedded val tableA: TableAEntity,
  @Relation(
    parentColumn = "parentAid",
    entityColumn = "parentAid"
  )
  val tableBList: List<TableBEntity>
)
```

Now select from ur room Database as below:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE parentAid=:id")
fun selectTableAWithTableB(id:Int): List<TableAWithTableB>
```

In the above code, the query returns a list of values for A with B. (List), meaning for every A a list of values from B will be returned where the parentAid is a foreign key in B.

Note: For more information please refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many